# Impecation of WhatsApp like "Load Earlier Messages" layout in Listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to make WhatsApp like "Load Earlier Messages" bar in Listview as shown in figure. I don't know what we say this kind of layout. If there is any tutorial available for that?

[image: WhatsApp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the chat window is a `ListView` and they're just adding a header view that contains a button.  You can just call `addHeaderView()` on the list.

Comment: Hi,how to implement the java class for whatsapp load earlier messages button in android?if possible provide the sample please.Thanks